# How to ensure website from hackers and more?

Tags: web-service, html

I'm really new to security in Websites, for example... So can someone give me somewhere to start please? Sorry if it's not the right place to ask... :|

Comment: First off, the word you're looking for is probably "secure", not "ensure". Secondly, you haven't even told us what operating system the server's running, so really the only piece of universal advice I can give would be "disconnect the machine from all networks, unplug it, and keep it under armed guard within the nearest lead-lined mountain".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hm. It really depends. There is many things to fix. Here are the most common hacker methods:
1. SQL Injection: Look up "How to prevent SQL Injection". SQL injection is a method hackers use to grab information from your site, like passwords. 
2. Denial-of-service: Denial-of-service, or DOSing is a attack on a website by sending an overflow of packets. This slows down the server, thus crashing the website. The fix? Not many, try a 5 second delay for anyone who enters your website. This makes packets travel much slower, and filters fake users from real users.
3. XSS: Cross-site-scripting isn't really a good way to protect your WEBSITE, but to protect YOURSELF from your website. Hackers sometimes inject scripts into your website and make the script get into your computer. These are all big ways hackers attack people.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely wide question. A short answer would be to start with the [OWASP](http://owasp.org) Web site and look at the introduction slides.

Comment: My teacher said that hackers get the information because they see what is being sent for example in a form in HTML even if its method is post. So I would want to learn how do you avoid it, for example.

Comment: @PichiWuana A hacker is simply a computer expert, an idiot using tools written by computer experts, or some combination of the aforementioned. So, before you study computer security, just **learn a lot more about computing**. Learn about computer networking, packet sniffing, Ethernet, TCP/IP, IPC, the memory layouts of binary formats, reflection... Fundamentally, computer security is about exploiting flaws in software (and, in the case of Van Eck phreaking, hardware), so to understand the flaws, you must understand how the software is supposed to work.

Comment: @PichiWuana Short version? A flaw in software lies in the difference between how that software is expected / assumed to behave, and how it actually behaves. In order to understand what's wrong with a piece of software, you must understand what it's supposed to do, first. You're trying to run a marathon before you've even run a mile.

Comment: @ParthianShot You're right. Where do I go when I know all this things...?

Comment: @PichiWuana The OWASP site is a good resource. Phrack is a good resource. Reading up on the Metasploit framework and playing with it is helpful. But to have the necessary background is just a lot of reading. Read a networking textbook cover-to-cover, an operating systems textbook, a compilers textbook, and any every manpage you can get your hands on. Look over Wireshark captures of your own traffic and, if you don't understand something, research it. And, of course, read questions and answers on SE sites (here, Stackoverflow, Serverfault...).